# Image Flashes to Full Size on iOS after keyframe scale transform

Tags: css, transform, css-animations, keyframe

We hit a weird iOS glitch when running the below CSS to animate some shapes flying across the page. The shapes start at full size and then slowly shrink and fade away, though at the end of the animation in Safari or Chrome on iOS, they flash back to full opacity with their full image size. It's just for a second, but with 15 of these objects flying across the page it's like popcorn. You can preview the issue here: http://visier.rps.is/. Any idea what's going on with this?

```
 #logo-one {
  opacity: 0;
  background: url("../img/animation-sprites.png") no-repeat;
  width: 52px;
  height: 58px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: changeSize-one 3s 5s infinite linear both;
  -moz-animation: changeSize-one 3s 5s infinite linear both;
  -o-animation: changeSize-one 3s 5s infinite linear both;
  animation: changeSize-one 3s 5s infinite linear both;
  right: -52px;
  position: absolute;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeSize-one {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    top: 120px;
    right: -52px;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: rotate(15deg) scale(0.77);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(0.77);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(0.77);
    right: 200px;
    top: 60px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.29);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.29);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.29);
    right: 430px;
    top: 0;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Does adding display:none; to the last keyframe help?

Comment: Adding display:none didn't seem to help. I event tried adding a keyframe at 0% that hid the shape and set it's opacity to 0 and then had a keyframe at 1% restore everything to the defaults, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the transform: translate CSS property instead of top and right?

```
transform: rotate(*) scale(*) translate(50px,100px);
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. The performance is WAY up on this animation now as well. The only other change I had to make was to reorder the transform elements to: transform: translate(50px,100px) scale(*) rotate(*);